# Regex in R : Find number followed by a pattern

Tags: r, regex

I am trying to make a regular expression which can extract number coming at any place after a pattern is matched.

```
df <-as.data.frame(cbind(c("The 100 price of apple is 2/1 and could be more than 30 ",
                           "The 200 price of fruits can be 20-1  and I am not sure how much it can decrease it can be 1", 
                           "The price is 120", 
                           "The price can be anything but less than 30 1", 
                           "The price 10",'there is price')))
df$v2 <- str_extract(df$V1, "price[^a-zA-Z]+\\d+.*")
```

My expected output in v2, basically first number after price and can be /- or space followed by number(2/1 or 2-1 or 2 1  :
price 2/1
price 20-1
price 120
price 30 1
price 10
Not Found
Regards, 
R

Comment: I have edited my question. I am looking for first number after price and number can be followed by / or - or space

Comment: Better! What about `"The price is 12+25"`? It's not clear if you want to return `"price 12"` or no match. In other words, what can follow the match? Again, please clarify by editing.

Comment: I don't know R but something looks odd. Should `str_extract`'s argument be `df` rather than `df$V1`? I believe `df` had been  `df$V1` before you edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sub` to extract digits which come after `"price"`.

```
sub('.*price.*?(\\d+)', '\\1', df$V1)
#[1] "2/1"  "20-1" "120"  "30 1" "10"
```

For updated data we can use :

```
stringr::str_match(df$V1, '.*price.*?(\\d+[-/ ]?\\d+?).*')[, 2]
#[1] "2/1"  "20-1" "120"  "30 1" "10"   NA
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Ronak. I am looking for only first instance of digits followed by a price.

Comment: @RBan I have updated the answer for the new dataset. Can you take a look?